# UICollectionView slider image is not showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, kingfisher

I am new to swift
I am trying to make a slider using UICollectionView which is working properly,

but when I try to implement cache (`Kingfisher`) it doesn't show my images in slider

here is my implementation

```
extension CompanyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if(self.sliderModel != nil){
    return (self.sliderModel?.data.count)!
   }else{
    return 0
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCollectionViewCell
    
     if(self.sliderModel != nil){
        
        if(self.sliderModel.data.count == indexPath.row){
            let url = URL(string:(self.sliderModel?.data[indexPath.row].experienceImage.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed ))!)
            cell.sliderImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }else{
            //cell.sliderImageView.image = self.imgArr[indexPath.row]
            let url = URL(string:(self.sliderModel?.data[indexPath.row].experienceImage.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed ))!)
            cell.sliderImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }
    }
    
    return cell
}
}
```

But Image is not visible in my slider, I checked my model I am getting the response from server and Images are there in image url.
May be I am downloading the Image at wrong place.

This is how I am getting my jsondata and assigning it in my model

```
func getBannerData(){
         dispatchGroup.enter()
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let appId = defaults.string(forKey: Constants.APPID)
        let token = "Bearer "+defaults.string(forKey: Constants.TOKEN)!
        if let url = URL(string: Constants.EXPERIENCE_BANNER_CENTER+appId!){
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
            APIManager.sharedInstance.getCall(request: request){
                (data) in
                if(!data.isEmpty){
                    do{
                        self.sliderModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(SliderModel.self, from: Data(data.utf8))
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.pageView.numberOfPages = (self.sliderModel?.data.count)!
                            self.sliderCollectionView.reloadData()
                           
                        }
                        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.changeImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                        
                        self.stopActivityIndicator()
                        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                    catch{
                        self.stopActivityIndicator()
                        self.showAlertMessage(alertMessage: Constants.COMMON_ERROR)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's some suspicious logic possibly unrelated to a cache problem.  Why fix the number of items to 10 instead of to the length of sliderModel?  Why access the model at the row-1?  For row == 0, that's a negative array index.

Comment: Hi @danh I updated my question

Comment: Okay, now I think the two branches of the conditional are identical and the nil check on slider model (in cellForItem) is superfluous, but these won't explain the image problem if you're still experiencing it.  As a learning step, I'd try to prove to myself, skipping over all of the collection view complexity, whether I can just get an image url from my model and use it to initialize a single image view hanging off the main view.

Comment: hi @danh,sorry for the complexity, and I tried just one Image, and only single Image is visible but it doesnt scroll neither download second image, but if I try to download Image before assigning in `cellForItem` it works fine.
my guess is there is something to do with `cellForItem`

Comment: @danh I have updated my question too, add few more details and code

Comment: I did a silly mistake in my counter thats why Images was not sliding after fixing it, it started working

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. You cannot network directly in `cellForItem`. You can ask for the download to begin now if needed, sure, but you cannot keep a reference to `cell`, because the user might scroll the cell out of view, and it might need to be reused, while the download is still taking place.

Instead, you must download into your *model* and then *reload* the collection view.

Comment: Hi @matt can you share any link which I can refer

Comment: @matt - I don't know much about the OP's caching image view library, but those typically retain the image view itself, and update upon completing the network task.